# How to pull the two most recent occurrences of a cost

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I've got a bit of a complex issue. My dataset has many different portfolios included in it, and each portfolio has a specific annual cost that I'm trying to track. When the cost comes in, I want to be able to compare it to the last time the cost was paid.

There are two problems:

1. Firstly, each portfolio incurs the cost in a different month, so I can't just pull the latest two dates the cost hit.
2. Secondly, sometimes, the cost is slightly delayed, so it may not be incurred in the same month every year.

Example:

[image]

Is there a way in either SQL or DAX to pull the two most recent occurrences of the cost for each portfolio?

TIA

Comment: Can you give an example for a portfolio? For example, which dates do you want to see for P5?

Comment: Why there is January, 2022 in the last row? it's a mismatch in data compare to other values.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, it's trivial, but also depends on your real table design / structure.

It would be helpful if you provided the CREATE TABLE statement(s) and sample INSERT statement(s) to show your test case.

Window functions is one approach.  Rough idea follows:

```
WITH xrows AS (
    SELECT portfolio, date, cost
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY portfolio ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS n
      FROM tbl
     )
SELECT *
  FROM xrows
 WHERE n <= 2
 ORDER BY portfolio, n
;
```

Row_number is used to assign row numbers within each portfolio separately, from 1 to number of rows in that portfolio, in the order specified.  The above is just grabbing the first two most recent rows for each portfolio by timestamp.  Obviously, the names are guesses until you provide the table structure.

Note: It's tough to know if you want to find the latest cost stored or the latest 2 costs stored.  That depends on your precise problem, which isn't clear above.